# check if there is any errors in lexer and parser java antlr4

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, antlr3

i am writing a grammar using antlr4 and i need to check if there is any errors in the lexer and parser,but i can't find an example of java code doing this.
here is my grammar and my java code .
[image]

[image]

Comment: Errors in lexer and parser? What's that? Do you mean errors in a source file?

Comment: yes,
when there is an errors it is printed on the console but me i want to know in my program .like this error ,how i can match it in the java program
"line 1:0 mismatched input 'is' expecting {'what', 'who', 'when', 'where'}
line 1:87 extraneous input '<EOF>' expecting {'?_.', 'when', 'of', 'for', 'during', 'in', 'at', 'on', 'since', 'while', 'according', 'between', 'with', 'today', 'this', 'last', 'yesterday'}"

Comment: You should try to grab a book like https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/the-definitive-antlr/9781941222621/f_0062.html There are also posts over the internet on relevant APIs.

Answer (score 0):

here is a class you can use it to check

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;

import java.util.*;

public class SyntaxError extends BaseErrorListener {
    private boolean error;

    public SyntaxError(){
        super();
        error = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer,
                            Object offendingSymbol,
                            int line, int charPositionInLine,
                            String msg,
                            RecognitionException e)
    {
        this.error = true;
    }
    public boolean isError() {
        return this.error;
    }
}
```

and you call it like that

```
parser.removeErrorListeners(); // remove ConsoleErrorListener
SyntaxError syntaxError = new SyntaxError();           
parser.addErrorListener(syntaxError); // add ours   
final ParseTree tree = parser.start();
if(syntaxError.isError){
// do what you want here
}
```